# asp.net mvc linq to sql issue with nullable variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net mvc project where have the search filter form and 8 parameters which arrive from my form and must be null. Everything work fine when I populate all fields in my search form. But when I hold missing fields it returns all rows from the table. I have the next expression:

```
var model = repository.GetRows()
.Where(x => x.Var1 == Var1 || x.Var2 == Var2 || 
x.Var3 == Var3 || x.Var4 == Var4 || 
x.Var5 == Var5 || x.Var6 == Var6 || 
x.Var7 == Var7 || x.Var8 == Var8).ToList();
```

Have any trick for checking the null variables? Because I have to write a lot of if/else statement, which I think it's not right.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `&&`?

Comment: Because when I use && it's return null statement, etc. none rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the null coalescing operator "??"

```
where(x => x.Var1 == (Var1 ?? x.Var1));
```

This simply says if Var1 is null then use the string "SomeValue".

Comment: But I need when my variable is null it mustn't include into my expression. What I should need to do in this scenario?

Comment: where(x => x.Var1 == (Var1 ?? x.Var1)); This will say if Var1 is null then return when x.var1 is equal to itself, making the clause cancel itself out.

Comment: where (x => x.Var1 == null || x.Var1 == Var1)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you to return IQueryable from  **repository.GetRows()**
then you can execute the query like :-

```
public List<Entity.Student> SearchStudent(string Name, int Age, string EmailAddress, string CountryName)
    {
        IQueryable<Entity.Student> lstStudents = this.GetAllStudent();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
        {
            lstStudents = lstStudents.Where(node => node.FirstName.Equals(Name) || node.LastName.Equals(Name));
        }
        if (Age > 0)
        {
            lstStudents = lstStudents.Where(node => node.Age == Age);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailAddress))
        {
            lstStudents = lstStudents.Where(node => node.Email.Equals(EmailAddress));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CountryName))
        {
            lstStudents = lstStudents.Where(node => node.Country .Equals(CountryName));
        }
        return lstStudents.ToList<Entity.Student>();
    }
```

this way is the recommended by DLinq  experts.

Comment: And when name != null & age != null, does it return only rows by Name?

Comment: or to lstStudents by name added lstStudents by Age?

Comment: if name and age are not null then it will generate the sql query like  :- select * from tblStudent where name = 'name' and age =10 then it will throw the result for you

Comment: can u think, what sql query this code will generate "where(x => x.Var1 == (Var1 ?? x.Var1));" it is adding one more condition to your sql query while there is no need of this condition. why we are adding one more condition in our sql query. it will hit the performance